# 2 person 2-factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a system as follows:

- User 1 is a low permission user. They will be using their phone and at some point will need to do a secure action.
- User 2 is an admin user and will be in the same room as user 1.
- User 2 will generate a temporary code on their own device (could be a phone or desktop), and then verbally give the code to user 1.
- User 1 will then enter the code given to them to complete the secure action.

Ideally, neither user 1 nor user 2 will reveal their account usernames to each other. The only thing that will be exchanged is the code.

The backend system I am using to build the basic user authentication is in ASP.NET Core MVC & Asp.net Identity, and this will include an API to validate and generate the codes.

Anyone have any ideas about how to implement the code generation and validation?
Potentially the codes will need to be long enough to identify which admin user requested the code (and thus approved the action), but hopefully not too long to become unwieldy (maybe 6-8 characters?)

(I posted this to stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073338/2-person-2-factor-authentication
but was recommended to post on this site. )

EDIT (more info):

So one of our main concerns is the anonymity and privacy of user 1. The application is basically a survey that collects personal data about user 1 and then user 2 supplies the code to approve and submit the survey. Afterwards when the data is being analyzed, we want to make sure that is not possible to identify which individual user 1 submitted the data, but we may still wish to be able to track which user 2 approved the data.

The code does not necessarily need to be relayed verbally, what is important: because of the pandemic, when don't want users touching the same phone, and hence user 2 cannot login to user 1's phone.

I like the idea of a push notification to user 2. However we are expecting concurrent use of this application, so I'm not certain how we would determine which supervisor/user 2 to send the request to?

For threats, our concern is to make sure the data submitted has been approved and that the anonymity of user 1 can be preserved.

Comment: You have a lot of unexplained requirements here. Why are account names a secret? Why do you need to log the id of User 2  who generated the code for User 1? Why can't User 2 log into User 1's device since they are in the same room? Why does the code need to be relayed verbally? Why can't you use a push notification to User 2's device to authorise like the process that's been in place for decades? And then, most importantly, **what threats are you trying to counter**?

Comment: The most likely use case that springs to mind is the kind of dual control required by parental supervision, assuming that the parent's device already has a PIN or other protections to prevent the approval codes from being acquired unattended.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks, I added more details to answer most of your questions. Could you elaborate more on how the push notification to user 2's device might work in this context?

Comment: Ok, your original description is an XY problem, and you mis-labelled the actors. It's not a low-priv user, it's a member of the public. And it's not an admin, but an approver. And there's no "account" and it's perfectly ok for the approver's system ID to be passed to the public.

Comment: The approver gives the user their ID (e.g. a 6-8 digit code). The system sends a confirmation to the approver's device, like the "password reset link" design pattern. The link the approver gets links to the submission for auditing purposes.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for helping me clarify this. So, the users filling out the survey need to be granted a username and password to get access to the app, and it will likely be members of an organization and not the public. I believe it is ok to pass the approver's system ID, but I'll check.